# Proper template for my iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c-2.0

I am building an iOS app, where I am doing a condition check for existance for a particular data. Please find the code I am using for Android,This condition check is done inside `SplashScreenActivty`

```
if(data.exists())
{
     startActivity(new Intent(this,Activate.class))
}else{
     startActivity(new Intent(this,Tabs.class))
}
```

How do I proceed with this logic in iOS. I am looking confused for selecting a template. Shall I go with for `SplashScreenActivity`. I have also found that iOS does not have anything like the SplashScreen. So how do I begin my app ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for this .

- Follow **first way**, if you want to display splash image only.
- Follow **second way** if you want to do some customisation programmatically in splash image

1:) Rename your image as **Default.png**

2:) Add new view controller with xib, write your stuff there in viewcontroller.m . Set timer using NSTimer & disappear it after your requiered time.

- // For first way // I assume you are creating your app for ***iPhone
  environment only*** not for iPad or universal
- // For second way // I assume you have ***not any click event***

Enjoy Programmming